# Laravel Routing multiple Params

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

i recently started using the framework Laravel as backend for my new project. For the frontend I use Angular 8+. Both areas are still relatively new to me and I am currently working on API routing and need your advice.

I have a user table where I store several user settings. I would like to update them accordingly. They are mostly boolean values. I now have a UserController. With this I want to process the PUT requests.

Now to my question: 
How should I set up the routing if I want to update the user settings at different actions.(e.g. Action1 update View1 + View2 or Action2 update View3)? Should I process all this in one function or in several functions within the controller? If there are several functions, how should the routing look like?

Multiple Routes and Function like this?

```
Route::middleware('api')->get('/user/{userid}', 'UserController@show');
Route::middleware('api')->put('/user/{userid}/updateViewAction1', 'UserController@updateViewAction1');
Route::middleware('api')->put('/user/{userid}/updateViewAction2', 'UserController@updateViewAction2');
```

or

If Statements within my function but how to update only data from the request? Angular transmits true/false from  therefore I check with if for true and set the value to 1.

```
public function updateView($userId, Request $request)
{
   if($request->query('view1') == "true"){ $view1 = 1; } else {$view1 = 0;}
   if($request->query('view2 ') == "true"){ $view2 = 1; } else {$view2  = 0;}
   $query = \DB::table('users')
             ->where('userId', '=', $userId)
             ->update(
                  ['view1' => $view1,
                  'view2 ' => $view2 );
}
```

It doesn't seem to be right, but I can't think of anything else. Authentication is not considered at this point. As there will be more than 20 settings in the future, I am looking for an efficient solution.

Comment: you have long way to go. sorry. no one could help with that kind of question. I just can suggest you to don't use if else in the controller. And you better use Dynamic Properties to update. and be sure that columns should be nullable in migration file.

Answer (score 0):

In controller you include the Request $request as the first argument, not the second

```php
public function updateView(Request $request, $userID)...
// Or
public function updateView(Request $request, User $userid)...
```

> Your are not oblidged to use the `::put` method, you can use `::post`